# files which are supposed to be ignore are still getting published after pushing them (.gitignore doesn't work)

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I tried the following steps: http://blog.jonathanchannon.com/2012/11/18/gitignore-not-working-fixed/

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"
```

but I just end up, after pushing it, with the files .gitignore was supposed to ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove individual files, using: `git rm --cached <file>`.

If the file is already commited and you would like to not push any new changes you can use:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

To list the ignored file you can use:

```
git ls-files -v | grep "^[[:lower:]]"
```

Comment: but why isn't gitignore working? I placed it in the root of my project, I used the python template (since it is a python project), shouldn't it be working?

Comment: @TsumugiKotobuki If the files are already tracked they are not affected by gitignore, see: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore, only the files that are not tracked yet are ignored. You can use the `update-index --assume-unchanged` approach in that case.